# Where does output go from SELECT in trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ssms

When I run a

```
SELECT * FROM inserted
```

from a trigger attached to the Insert event of a table, where does the output go? I am using SSMS to append the row to the table so the trigger fires while I am in SSMS.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. It would end up as part of the result set from a query batch. So in SSMS it will be in the results tab.

Comment: Outputting a dataset from a Trigger is Deprecated by the way; if you have solutions that use that functionality it is advised you change it.

Comment: I didn't know that was deprecated @Larnu. Of course I have never actually considered that as it seems like the wrong approach to how a trigger should work. I guess that is why it is deprecated and apparently has been since sql 2012.

Comment: I agree, @SeanLange . If you really need data from the inserted values, that's what the `OUTPUT` clause is for.

Comment: Even before the OUTPUT clause existed I never considered needing to return data from a trigger.